# Cython embedding error

Tags: cython, python-3.6

I am trying to use Cython for a Python 3.6.1 application on a Raspberry Pi 3 (under Ubuntu Mate 16.04.2).

Converting sub modules (and leaving main.py) works without problems:

```
python3.6 -m cython sub.py
gcc -shared -pthread -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing -I/usr/local/include/python3.6m -s -o sub.so sub.c
strip sub.so
```

sub.so can be used from main.py without problems.

But converting main.py does not:

```
python3.6 -m cython --embed main.py
gcc -pthread -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing -I/usr/local/include/python3.6m -o main main.c  -L/usr/local/lib  -lpython3.6m -lpthread -lm -lutil -ldl
```

main is generated.

But executing it produces:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 8, in init main (main.c:6814)
import math
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/math.cpython-36m-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so: undefined symbol: PyLong_FromDouble
```

Removing the math import in main.py leads to similar problems with other symbols.

What is missing?

Comment: Looks like it is missing some Cython imports.  First try adding `cimport cython` in main.py and try again.  I usually just write a PYX so not sure what -embed actually does under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

The function "PyLong_FromDouble" is located in the "libpython3.*.a" archive.  If you linked the main executable which was running the Python interpreter to this static library, you have to make sure:
1) the code for this function is not dropped, and
2) the symbol is exported.

For 1), try the "--whole-archive" linker option, or just place the ".a" file like a ".o" instead of referring to it as a library with "-l".
For 2), try the "-E" (or "--export-dynamic") linker option to export all symbols, because there are lots of them in "libpython3.*.a" anyway.